# Proving that $\|A\|=\max(|a|,|b|)$ on $C[a,b]$ for the multiplication by $x$ operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $$X=C[a,b] \ , A||{\Psi}||_\infty=\underset{a\leq x\leq b}{\max}|\Psi(x)|$$  Let $A$ be the multiplication by $x$.

I want to prove that $$||A||=\max(|a|,|b|)$$

Solution:

$$||{A}||=\underset{a\leq ||x||\leq b}{\sup}||{x}||=\sqrt{x^2}$$ which gives

$$a x||\Psi||_{\infty} \leq x\cdot x |\Psi(x)| \leq b x||\Psi||_{\infty}$$

Then we have
$||A\Psi(x)|| =a x||\Psi||_{\infty} \leq x ^2|\Psi(x)| \leq bx ||\Psi||_{\infty}$.

Hence

$$ax ||\Psi||_{\infty} \le||A \Psi||_{\infty} \le bx ||\Psi||_{\infty}.$$

$$||A \Psi||_{\infty} =bx =bx ||\Psi||_{\infty} \longrightarrow ||{A}||\leqslant xb$$

Therefore

$$||A||\le xb.$$

But I can't find a good way to show that this must also imply that $$||A||=max(|a|,|b|)$$.

So I tried this:

We then prove that $||A||=\max(|a|,|b|)$, where $A$ is the multiplication operator. It is sufficient to show that for the metric

$$d(x,y)=|x(t)-y(t)|=\underset{a\le t\le b}{sup}\sqrt{ x(t)^2+y(t)^2}\leq \epsilon $$

and since $$\underset{a\le t\le b}{\max}\sqrt{ x(t)^2+y(t)^2}\leq \epsilon$$

then

$$A||{\Psi}||_\infty=\underset{a\leq x\leq b}{\max}|\Psi(x)|\leq \epsilon$$

since the norm of the multiplication operator has the following properties:

$$||{A}||=||xf||=||x||\cdot||f||=||{x}||\cdot\underset{a\le t\le b}{\max}|x-y|$$

and since we operator on the interval  $[a,b]$ we get:

$$||{A}||={\max}(|a|,|b|)$$

But I am not sure this is sufficient?

Thanks

Comment: You have mis-understood the definition of $A$. $Af(x)=xf(x)$ for all $f \in C[a,b]$ and $x \in [a,b]$.

Comment: How did you get $||{A}||=\underset{a\leq ||x||\leq b}{sup}||{x}||=\sqrt{x^2}$?

Comment: @geetha290krm see my update

Comment: Please use `\|` for the norms and `\max`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be some misunderstanding about both the role of $A$, and the definition of the operator norm. $A:X
\to X$ is simply defined, for any $f\in X$, to be the function $Af$, which is defined for any $x\in[a,b]$ by $(Af)(x)=xf(x)$. The norm of $A$ is the usual operator norm (which we shall denote $\|\cdot\|_{op}$ to distinguish it from the norm on $X$), which is defined by
$$\|A\|_{op}:=\sup_{\|f\|\leq 1}\|Af\|=\sup_{\|f\|\leq 1}\max_{x\in[a,b]}|xf(x)|. $$
Now, for all such $f$ which we are taking the supremum over, $|f(x)|\leq 1$ for all $x\in[a,b],$ meaning that
$$\|A\|_{op}\leq \max_{x\in[a,b]}|x|=\max\{|a|,|b|\}.$$
Finally, note that for any $g\in X$ with $\|g\|\leq 1$ we have, by definition, that $\sup_{\|f\|\leq 1} \|Af\|\geq\|Ag\|$. Now set $g=\mathbf 1$, where $\mathbf 1(x)=1$ for all $x\in [a,b]$. Thus
$$\|A\|_{op}\geq\|Ag\|=\max_{x\in[a,b]}|x\mathbf 1(x)|=\max_{x\in[a,b]}|x|=\max\{|a|,|b|\}.$$
Combining the above two inequalities gives the result.

Comment: THanks for this . Note there is a formatting error at $\|\cdot\|_{op}$